# Stop the change of the open activitiy owners tasks when an account owner is changed

Tags: apex

Below is a given code which is supposed to stop the changing of the ownership of open activities.  Whenever account owner changes in SF, it changes all of the open activitiy owners of tasks to the new owner of the account. That is what I want to avoid.

```
trigger preventTaskOwnerChange on Account(after update) {

    list < task > updatetask = new list < task > ();
    for (account a: trigger.new) {
        string oldownerid = trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).OwnerId;
        string newownerid = a.ownerid;
        if (oldownerid != newownerid) {

            for (account acc: [select OwnerId, (select OwnerId from tasks) from account]) {
                for (task tsk: acc.tasks) {

                    tsk.ownerId = oldownerid;
                    updatetask.add(tsk);


                }

            }
            update updatetask;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not working as expected and what I would like to achieve is when an account owner is changed in SF the open activitiy owners tasks to remain unchanged. 
Could you please advise how to avoid the situation of changing of the open activitiy owners taks.

Comment: Maybe you could close the tasks and reopen later in a queuable, assuming there is a system process which is steamrollering your task update.

Comment: The ownership change of tasks happens after triggers, much like roll up summary fields. Asynchronous code would be ideal.

Comment: I have found a solution for non-recurring tasks, however I am looking to find a general solution for the recurring tasks as well. Could you please advise how to avoid the situation of changing of the open activitiy owners recurring taks.