# Best way to prevent reassignment of tasks on account ownership change?

Tags: account, tasks

I was hoping to see if anyone had found a good solution for preventing open tasks from being reassigned when an account's owner changes. I've seen some options as triggers, but the few I've tried haven't worked very well.

Essentially, if the account is owned by User1 and there's a handful of tasks on the account owned by User1, then the account is changed over to User2, I want those tasks to remain owned by User1.

Comment: sfdcfox has this one pegged here - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77274/stop-the-change-of-the-open-activitiy-owners-tasks-when-an-account-owner-is-chan  . You'll need to do this in an asynchronous process that runs after the account DML is completed

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this.

```
    /*
    Created by: Greg Hacic
    Last Update: 28 January 2010 by Greg Hacic
    Questions?: greg@interactiveties.com
*/
trigger reassignRelatedContactsAndOpportunities on Account (after update) {
    try {
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>(); //set for holding the Ids of all Accounts that have been assigned to new Owners
        Map<Id, String> oldOwnerIds = new Map<Id, String>(); //map for holding the old account ownerId
        Map<Id, String> newOwnerIds = new Map<Id, String>(); //map for holding the new account ownerId
        Contact[] contactUpdates = new Contact[0]; //Contact sObject to hold OwnerId updates
        Opportunity[] opportunityUpdates = new Opportunity[0]; //Opportunity sObject to hold OwnerId updates

        for (Account a : Trigger.new) { //for all records
            if (a.OwnerId != Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).OwnerId) {
                oldOwnerIds.put(a.Id, Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).OwnerId); //put the old OwnerId value in a map
                newOwnerIds.put(a.Id, a.OwnerId); //put the new OwnerId value in a map
                accountIds.add(a.Id); //add the Account Id to the set
            }
        }

        if (!accountIds.isEmpty()) { //if the accountIds Set is not empty
            for (Account act : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Contacts), (SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunities WHERE IsClosed = False) FROM Account WHERE Id in :accountIds]) { //SOQL to get Contacts and Opportunities for updated Accounts
                String newOwnerId = newOwnerIds.get(act.Id); //get the new OwnerId value for the account
                String oldOwnerId = oldOwnerIds.get(act.Id); //get the old OwnerId value for the account
                for (Contact c : act.Contacts) { //for all contacts
                    if (c.OwnerId == oldOwnerId) { //if the contact is assigned to the old account Owner
                        Contact updatedContact = new Contact(Id = c.Id, OwnerId = newOwnerId); //create a new Contact sObject
                        contactUpdates.add(updatedContact); //add the contact to our List of updates
                    }
                }
                for (Opportunity o : act.Opportunities) { //for all opportunities
                    if (o.OwnerId == oldOwnerId) { //if the opportunity is assigned to the old account Owner
                        Opportunity updatedOpportunity = new Opportunity(Id = o.Id, OwnerId = newOwnerId); //create a new Opportunity sObject
                        opportunityUpdates.add(updatedOpportunity); //add the opportunity to our List of updates
                    }
                }
            }
            update contactUpdates; //update the Contacts
            update opportunityUpdates; //update the Opportunities
        }
    } catch(Exception e) { //catch errors
        System.Debug('reassignRelatedContactsAndOpportunities failure: '+e.getMessage()); //write error to the debug log
    }
}
```

Source : - [link](https://www.interactiveties.com/blog/2010/apex-reassign-contacts.php#.ViBpzeyqqko)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're facing the issue of Salesforce automatically updating the owner of open activities when changing the owner of parent records (e.g., Opportunities, Contacts), you can resolve this by utilizing the PreventOpenActivityOwnerChange solution.

[PreventOpenActivityOwnerChange](https://github.com/Dheeraj5861/PreventOpenActivityOwnerChange) is a GitHub repository containing Apex code that overrides Salesforce's default behavior. It allows you to maintain control over ownership updates, preventing the automatic modification of open activity owners during parent record ownership changes.

#### Solution Steps:

1. **Clone the Repository:**
   Clone the PreventOpenActivityOwnerChange repository to your local machine.

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/Dheeraj5861/PreventOpenActivityOwnerChange.git
   ```
2. **Deploy Apex Code:**
   Deploy the provided Apex code to your Salesforce environment.
3. **Customize as Needed:**
   Feel free to customize the code to meet your specific business requirements.
4. **Contribute:**
   If you have improvements or enhancements, consider contributing to the repository by submitting a pull request.

Remember to test thoroughly in a sandbox environment before deploying to production.

Feel free to [check out the repository](https://github.com/Dheeraj5861/PreventOpenActivityOwnerChange)

Happy coding!

---